# How to load a csv into a table in Q?

Tags: database, kdb

Very new to Q and I am having some issues loading my data into a table following the examples on the documentation.

I am running the following code:

```
table1: get `:pathname.csv
```

While it doesn't throw an error, when I run the following command nothing comes up:

```
select * from table1
```

Or when selecting a specific column:

```
select col1 from table1
```

If anyone could guide me in the right direction, that would be great!

Edit: This seems to work and retain all my columns:

```
table1: (9#"S";enlist csv) 0: `:data.CSV
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're going to need to use `0:` https://code.kx.com/q/ref/filenumbers/#load-csv

The exact usage will depend on your csv, as you need to define the datatypes to load each column as.

As an example, here I have a CSV with a long, char & float column:

```
(kdb) chronos@localhost ~/Downloads $ more example.csv 
abc,def,ghi
1,a,3.4
2,b,7.5
3,c,88
(kdb) chronos@localhost ~/Downloads $ q
KDB+ 3.6 2018.10.23 Copyright (C) 1993-2018 Kx Systems
l64/ 4()core 3894MB chronos localhost 127.0.0.1 EXPIRE 2019.06.15 jonathon.mcmurray@aquaq.co.uk KOD #5000078

q)("JCF";enlist",")0:`:example.csv
abc def ghi
-----------
1   a   3.4
2   b   7.5
3   c   88 
q)meta ("JCF";enlist",")0:`:example.csv
c  | t f a
---| -----
abc| j    
def| c    
ghi| f    
q)
```

I use the chars `"JCF"` to define the datatypes long, character & float respectively.

I `enlist` the delimiter (`","`) to indicate that the first row of the CSV contains the headers for the columns. (Otherwise, these can be supplied in your code & the table constructed)

On a side note, note that in q-sql, the `*` is not necessary as in standard SQL;  you can simply do `select from table1` to query all columns

Comment: Thanks for the response, I believe it’s loading up. In order to call the table, I will have to assign it. When I put “table1” in front of the statement it fails. Any way to assign a table differently then?

Comment: Using my example above, it would be ``table1:("JCF";enlist",")0:`:example.csv`` Perhaps you missed the `:` ?